How to Preserve Tracked Changes (Redlining) When Converting Word Document to HTML Using .NET C# and OpenXmlPowerTools?
I am working on a project where I need to convert a Word document to HTML format using .NET C#. For this task, I am using the OpenXmlPowerTools library. The conversion works fine, except for one critical issue: the redlining (tracked changes) present in the Word document does not appear in the HTML output.
Here's what I have tried so far:
Followed the standard procedure for using OpenXmlPowerTools to convert the document.
Verified that the tracked changes are present in the original Word document.
Experimented with various settings and methods provided by the library to ensure tracked changes are preserved in the output.
Despite these efforts, I am unable to get the tracked changes to show up in the HTML file.
My questions are:
Are there specific settings or methods in OpenXmlPowerTools that ensure the preservation of tracked changes in the HTML output?
Are there alternative libraries or tools within the .NET ecosystem that handle this conversion more effectively?
Any examples or documentation that might help resolve this issue would be highly appreciated.
Code which I am using from OpenXmlPowerTools.
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using OpenXmlPowerTools;

public void ConvertDocToHtml(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(inputFile, true))
    {
        HtmlConverterSettings settings = new HtmlConverterSettings()
        {
            FabricateCssClasses = true,
            CssClassPrefix = "pt-",
            RestrictToSupportedLanguages = false,
            RestrictToSupportedNumberingFormats = false,
        };
        
        XElement html = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(doc, settings);

        // Save the HTML to file
        File.WriteAllText(outputFile, html.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
    }
}

Word document
Word document
Expected Result in html
Expected Result in html
Actual Result in html
Actual Result in html
